# Block fsockopen() errors

Tags: php

I would like to block the errors that fsockopen() gives me.

> (Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to 50.31.65.135:27015 (Connection timed out) in /home/reverbga/public_html/query/query.php on line 6)

I just want it to not show that, as I use fsockopen as a way to see if the server is online.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$serialized = file_get_contents('http://module.game-monitor.com/50.31.65.135:27015/data/server.php');
$players = unserialize($serialized);
$array = (array) $players;

$fp = fsockopen("50.31.65.135", 27015, $errno, $errstr, 1);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "<img width='20' height='20' src='bullet_red.png' />OCRP: OFFLINE";
}
else {
    echo "<img width='20' height='20' src='bullet_green.png' />OCRP: {$array['player']}/{$array['maxplayer']}";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [suppressing the error](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

```
$fp = @fsockopen("50.31.65.135", 27015, $errno, $errstr, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a sign like this @ before your fsockopen handler

```
<?php
$serialized = file_get_contents('http://module.game-monitor.com/50.31.65.135:27015/data/server.php');
$players = unserialize($serialized);
$array = (array) $players;

@$fp = fsockopen("50.31.65.135", 27015, $errno, $errstr, 1);

if (!$fp) {
echo "<img width='20' height='20' src='bullet_red.png' />OCRP: OFFLINE";
}
else {
  echo "<img width='20' height='20' src='bullet_green.png' />OCRP:{$array['player']}/{$array['maxplayer']}";
}  

?>
```